# Is there software that interpolates/extrapolates data using a discrete Fourier?

Tags: fourier-analysis, math-software, interpolation, extrapolation

I've read various methods of Fourier interpolation and extrapolation detailed in articles such as [Interpolation and Extrapolation Using a
High-Resolution Discrete Fourier Transform](http://saig.physics.ualberta.ca/saig/papers/Sacchi_Ulrych_Walker_IEEE_98.pdf)—so what I'm wondering is, has anyone actually implemented this anywhere?

I would like to experiment with extrapolating and interpolating data and audio and 2D data like pictures, if possible.  Especially extrapolating.

(I would also like to know if any software is freely available.)

Comment: looking at the equations, matlab should be of help, but its gonna take some effort

Comment: May I suggest e-mailing any of the authors to ask if they've written any software for this, before you go through the trouble of implementing it yourself?

Comment: Will do.  Meantime I'm more interested in whether anyone other than the authors implemented it.

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-extrapolate-a-1d-signal